# What does "- <" mean when you run powershell?

Tags: powershell, teamcity

The recommended way to run scripts is

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -Command " & some.ps1 "
```

However for example TeamCity PowerShell runner uses:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -Command - < some.ps1
```

I do not have an idea what "- <" means and cannot find any information on subject. Any help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `powershell.exe` is being invoked through the Windows shell, it is the same as if you were on a normal command prompt (`cmd.exe`). In that situation `<` pipes a file to the standard input (`stdin`) of the previous command. The help for `powershell.exe` states that if the value of `-Command` is simply `-`, the command text is read from standard input.

Here's a more self-documenting demonstration of `<` in `cmd.exe`:

```
processSomeFile.exe outputFileName.ext < intputFile.ext
```

Comment: Wow, this is the way to bypass execution policy. I was able to execute a script in this way with Restricted policy.

Comment: I wonder, is PowerShell team aware of this? What is the value then in having execution policy Restricted by default?

Comment: Not really a security concern, as I see it. You'd have to have local access to the machine (physical, Remote Desktop, etc.) anyway in order to pipe to `stdin`, meaning you could `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to lift restrictions and basically do whatever you please. (In other words, you'd have to have the ability to execute things on the machine in the first place. This doesn't open a door because the door would already be open.)

Comment: I am not talking about attacks from outside. Scenario: a user is already at the machine. His/her system administrator denied execution of PS scripts for him/her for some reasons. A user still can bypass this, as we can see.

Comment: Can the administrator deny the user the ability to use `Set-ExecutionPolicy`?

Comment: Yes, of course -- ` Set-ExecutionPolicy` is about the registry access, in fact.

Comment: Hmmm: [`about_Execution_Policies`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347641.aspx).

Comment: @Roman Kuzmin - Execution policy is not intended as a security feature, but to prevent accidental running of scripts that you did not intend to. Any security restriction applied by the Administrator to the account initiating the script / command will apply.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the value of Command is "-", the command text is read from
   standard  input.
2. < is just the stdout -> stdin redirection operator

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the recommaneded way to execute a **script** is with the -File parameter:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -Command -File some.ps1
```

With regard to your question, the '<' character is reserved and cannot be used in PowerShell.

Comment: For clarity, the OP's `<` is being passed to cmd.exe which is a different ball game so point that out in this context is a bit of a red herring...

Answer (score 0):

Using the I/O operators like > and < in a bash script means that you **write** output to an external file i.e. :

```
echo hello > hello.txt
```

or you **get** input from an external file i.e. :

```
psql -U test test < script.sql
```

the same logic is applied to the windows powershell, you can get more infos [HERE](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Windows_PowerShell_1.0_Pipes_and_Redirection)